# Using Android:tag() To locate file in asset

Tags: android

I want to use `android:tag` to locate file on asset how to do this? I cannot use double quotes.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:src="@drawable/sar90"
    android:onClick="openpdf"
    android:tag=""file:///android_asset/pdf/example.pdf""
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

To send path file to this method

```
public void openpdf(View v) {
    String url2 = (String) v.getTag();
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PDF.class);
    i.putExtra("key", url2);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and in `PDF.class`,

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String url2 = extras.getString("key");
PDFView pdfView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
pdfView.fromAsset(url2).load();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since URL is basically a string, you can put it into values/strings.xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="myurl">http://something</string>
</resources>

 android:tag="@string/myurl"
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra quotes,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:onClick="openpdf"
    android:src="@drawable/sar90"
    android:tag="file:///android_asset/pdf/example.pdf" />
```